# Access to historical Dialogflow data

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We use Dialogflow ES. Is there a way to access historical conversational data from Dialogflow or GCP that includes utterance, intent mapping, and confidence score for each utterance?

Thank you,
Daren

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to access historical conversational logs via Dialogflow console. You can check this out by:

- Open dialogflow console, select your agent
- On the menu at the left side click "History"
- Conversations are logged in a chronological order
- Select and expand a conversation
- There is a "more menu" at the right most part of an "Agent" conversation, click it
- Choose "Raw interaction log". The content of this log is [detectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse).

The `detectIntentResponse` contains the utterance, the mapped intent for it, confidence score, etc. You can see all the fields of `detectIntentResponse` [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/DetectIntentResponse). For further information you can read [History logs in Dialogflow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/history).

Here is a snippet of a historical conversation:
[image]

Please take note that there is **no way to retrieve the logs via the Dialogflow API**, thus we are only able view it in the Dialogflow console. But you can check [Is there a way to retrieve the conversation history in Dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377634/14733669), for the stackdriver alternative where you can use the Stackdriver API to get the logs and probably store them somewhere.